# Slickgrid - Avoiding jquery conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using slickgrid with jquery 1.7 on a site where I also have to use jquery 1.8. If I only include jquery 1.8. column resizing does not work.

Therefore I'm asking whether slickgrid supports jquery 1.8. or whether there is an option in slickgrid to tell slickgrid which jquery version to use.

This question has also been asked in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/slickgrid/aqkI0bG-UWw) google group thread.

Comment: Why are you using two versions of jQuery?

Comment: Cause Bootstrap 2 needs jquery 1.8 for some features and slickgrid needs (at least for column resizing) jquery 1.7.

Comment: You should be able to safely use jQuery 1.8 and jQueryUI 1.9 with the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [pull request to address this issue](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/462). It's a one line fix… beyond me why it has yet to be accepted into the master branch.